# Plotting the exponential of 1/(y-x)

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

What is the best way to handle this situation?

```
f[x_, y_] = Exp[1/(x - y)];
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Comment: You can keep the original definition of the function and just add `Exclusions -> x == y` to the plot.

Comment: @m_goldberg: Seems to clean up the graph just fine: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hug0F.png

Comment: @Rahul Excellent! Thanks for the great help. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am presuming you want to eliminate the singularity. Perhaps this will work for you.

```
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_] /; Abs[x - y] > .05 := Exp[1/(x - y)]
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  ClippingStyle -> None,
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Instead of .05, which I chose arbitrarily, you may find a smaller value more to your liking.

[image: plot]

You could also do what Rahul suggested in a comment, but you will need to use `Quiet` to suppress the error messages.

```
Quiet @ 
  Plot3D[Exp[1/(x - y)], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
    Exclusions -> x == y,
    ClippingStyle -> None,
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
    AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

This gives the a plot that is indistinguishable form the one shown above.

Comment: My helper is back! Thanks. However, I do not understand the function notation. Can you help me with what `f[x_, y_] /; Abs[x - y] > .05 := Exp[1/(x - y)]` does?

Comment: @David. `/;` is the operator form of the function[`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html), which you should study. You will find very useful. In this case it makes `f` undefined in the region of the singularity, so `Plot3D` doesn't try to plot there.

Comment: @David. I can make nothing of your "Ouch" comment. There is nothing in my answer that can destroy anything you have in your notebook. `Clear[f]` could delete previous definitions of `f` from your working kernel, which is what it should do, since they might interfere with the new definition. But it can't destroy anything in the notebook itself.

Comment: My bad. I just have two functions f in the global workspace now.

Comment: Two absolutely wonderful explanations. Thanks to both of you.